# Cordova FCM plugin handle background notification data

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm using the following code to receive data on my ionic app using firebase, i'm getting data.wastapped = true when the app is in background now i need to pass the data to my main controller,please help me to achieve this

```
 FCMPlugin.onNotification(
                        function(data){
                            if(data.wasTapped){
    alert(JSON.stringify(data);
    // need to pass this data to my app controller

                                tapped by the user.
                                alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
                            }else{

                                alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
                            }
                        },
                        function(msg){
                            alert('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
                        },
                        function(err){
                            alert('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ram,
Try using this below function

```
var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('mainbody')).scope();   
scope.$apply(function(){
           //show popup regarding alert         
            scope.showdatas(data);
        });
```